# Wordpress replace variable with name

Tags: wordpress

I have this code

```
<'.if (get_post_meta($post->ID,"_as_roomtype",true) == 'DE').'>
<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="readnow" >"---NAME---"</a>
```

I have values on "meta_value" like "DE", "UK", "SP"

I need to make something like that.

```
if the value on "meta_value" = "DE" show Germany on "---NAME---"
if the value on "meta_value" = "UK" show United Kingdom on "---NAME---"
if the value on "meta_value" = "SP" show Spain on "---NAME---"
```

How can I make this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$meta_values = array('DE' => 'Germany', 'UK' => 'United Kingdom', 'SP' => 'Spain');
if ($meta_key = get_post_meta($post->ID,"_as_roomtype",true)):
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" class="readnow" ><?php echo $meta_values[$meta_key]; ?></a>
```